# Does this time format look familiar?

Tags: datetime, format

Can someone help me tell what datetime format is this, or what are it's parts?

e.g.

- `201106020539Z0000031552001001`
- `201106020702Z0000000000001`
- `201105140701Z0000000000001`
- `201105170207A0000018560001001`

I think I've got the first few parts (`201106020539` is `yyyymmddhhmm`), but from the `Z` / `A` character onward, I have no clue. Is it possible that the rest isn't a datetime at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Z implies Zulu or UTC time https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/so-html-formats-time-incorrectly, as for what comes after, I don't know since all other time data has already been indicated prior to the Timezone Character.

Also, the fact that your timestamps don't seem to end in the same number of characters suggests they might not be the same format/spec? Where did you obtain them?

Comment: Thanks. But what about the A? The numbers after them?

Comment: I imagine it might be another timezone abbreviation?

Comment: @john2x: A is Zulu+1 http://www.time.gov/images/worldzones.gif. It's less commonly used, but it matches Central-Eastern Europe. (there could be other meanings for it, but this is the most common usage I've seen of it)

Comment: Some software where I work takes data from a database and spits out a text file with these numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In which context did you get these strings? I would guess that the digits are the seconds fractions.

[Maybe this helps you:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

> For a UTC time (a DateTime.Kind
>   property value of DateTimeKind.Utc),
>   the result string includes a "Z"
>   character to represent a UTC date.